# Fisher-Yates shuffle: Who is right, .NET 8 or Wikipedia?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

Was looking for shuffling an array from within Unity, remembered that .NET 8 has [Random.Shuffle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shuffle?view=net-8.0).

It turns out that the implementation is the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

But when looking at it and at Wikipedia page, they're not 100% identical.

[.NET 8 source:](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs,d66f8729c2195477)

```
public void Shuffle<T>(Span<T> values)
{
    int n = values.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = Next(i, n);

        if (j != i)
        {
            T temp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[j];
            values[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

[Wikipedia, "inside-out" variant:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_%22inside-out%22_algorithm)

```
To initialize an array a of n elements to a randomly shuffled copy of source, both 0-based:
  for i from 0 to n − 1 do
      j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
      if j ≠ i
          a[i] ← a[j]
      a[j] ← source[i]
```

The .NET version does everything within the `if` block, not Wikipedia's.

**Question:**

Which one of these is right and can you explain why it is?

Comment: Why did you pick the "inside-out" variant from the Wikipedia page? The algorithm .NET implemented is the one described in the "the modern algorithm" section of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @trincot Okay, got it.

Comment: @Sweeper Wasn't so sure in the end, hence the question.

Comment: @Sweeper If you look at the modern algorithm, it differs significantly from .NET's.

Comment: No it is not. It's the one starting with "for i from 0 to n−2 do...". Perhaps the notation of the loop confused you? Notice the C# loop also loops from 0 to n - 2 - it's a `<` not `<=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wikipedia explains, this *inside-out* variant is *initialising* a target array that is different from the source array. The algorithm you quote from NET.8 is an *inplace* algorithm also described in the same Wikipedia article.

When a different array must receive the shuffled data, then an assignment has to happen to *each* index of the target array. This is why that assignment is not part of the conditional block.

The *inplace* algorithm can detect the situation where a value happens not to move and so the swap does not have to be executed.

The NET.8 version corresponds to what Wikipedia calls *"An equivalent version which shuffles the array in the opposite direction"*. Admittedly Wikipedia performs the swap unconditionally. Of course, if `i` and `j` are the same this swap is a no-op, and apparently NET.8 coders have found that it is worth it to perform an extra `if` comparison in each iteration so to save on executing a swap when both indices are equal.

Comment: Now it's much more clear thanks to your explanations!

Comment: As an aside, the branch is probably costlier than simply performing the swap for integers; it's likely there for more elaborate (value) types.